# How to get results for individual fields per second

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have the following query which gives me per second average results for the events. 
Is there a way I can modify it to produce the individual average results for each CLIENT? Thanks.

```
 index=some_some2_idx ns=something app_name=my-api 
 CLIENT IN (Apple, Orange, Banana) API IN (R_GET, T_GET) 
 | timechart span=1s count as requests_per_second | stats avg(requests_per_second)
```

This is currently outputting:

```
avg(requests_per_second)
 18.39494
```

I am looking to get results as follows:

```
Apple     Orange     Banana
 5.1       5.9        7.39
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
index=some_some2_idx ns=something app_name=my-api 
 CLIENT IN (Apple, Orange, Banana) API IN (R_GET, T_GET) 
 | timechart span=1s count by CLIENT | stats AVG(*) by *
```